# How to split the date range into days using script

Tags: shell-script, shell, hadoop

I have this input:

```
      startdate             end date         val1    val2
2015-10-13 07:00:02 2015-10-19 00:00:00      45      1900
```

in which one line specifies a date range that spans multiple days,
and I want to split the range into separate time periods,
each one being a subset of a day (each one on a separate line),
to facilitate parallel processing of the (multi-day) range.

The output should be

```
2015-10-13 07:00:02 2015-10-13 23:59:59      45      1900
2015-10-14 00:00:01 2015-10-14 23:59:59      45      1900
2015-10-15 00:00:01 2015-10-15 23:59:59      45      1900
2015-10-16 00:00:01 2015-10-16 23:59:59      45      1900
2015-10-17 00:00:01 2015-10-17 23:59:59      45      1900
2015-10-18 00:00:01 2015-10-18 23:59:59      45      1900
2015-10-19 00:00:01 2015-10-19 00:00:00      45      1900
```

where the data after the end time (val1 and val2)
are replicated on each line.

1. Actually the input records are coming from the hive table and the output records also will store it in split table.

Modifications:

date split is fine. need to split the val2 value also as per the split date.

if the date diff is 2 then we would split 2 rows that should be

- **row 1:**

ratio= ratio of timespent 1st day (i.e. end-start on day 1)  / **val1**

val2= ratio*val2

- **row 2:**

ratio= ratio of timespent 1st day (i.e. end-start on day 2)  / **val1**

**val2** = ratio*val2

How can I script this?

Comment: Welcome to [Unix.SE]! You might want to have a look at the formatting help in [edit] mode to get nicely formatted text. ;) As it stands, your question is rather unclear and hard to answer: What's the exact pattern your result should be following? Are you looking to solve this in a particular scripting language? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes, you can do all kinds of things to that file. What is your goal?

Comment: I've edited in my understanding of your question.  Clarify if I'm wrong.  But even if I'm right, I don't understand the final range: October 19th from 00:00:01 to 00:00:00?  Is that *really* what you want output?

Comment: No. i didn't tried. i have worked small kind of scripts.
I want some one to share the script for this. i could understand that and will elaborate for my requirement.@n.st

Comment: yes  today's start date HH:MM:SS+1 as yesterday's end date HH:MM:SS.

means 
2015-10-13 07:00:02          2015-10-13 23:59:59

2015-10-14 00:00:00          2015-10-14 23:59:59

the  date should be split till the end dtae@Wildcard

Comment: my goal is to split the date.if the date difference of start date and end date is >=1.@jpaugh

Comment: OK, that was a good first step, but it needs more work.  (1) Check for typos.  You say, “row **2**: … **1st** day (i.e. end−start on day **2**) …”  Everything else about row 2 refers to the 2nd day; do you really mean to be saying “1st day” there?  (2) Don’t just write formulas; ***write sentences***.  Explain what your objective is, or at least what the formulas *mean*. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  For example, how should I interpret “ratio of time spent 1st day (i.e., end−start on day 1) / val1”?  Is it 17/45=0.377 (since there are 17 hours on day 1)?  (17/24)/45=0.708/45=0.0157 (since 17 hours is 0.708 days)?  (17/137)/45=0.124/45=0.00275 (since the entire period is 137 hours, and your comment mentioned “total time”)?  (3) Your comment said that you wanted val1 computed as something (unclear) divided by val2.  Your question says that you want val2 computed based on something divided by val1.  Check for typos.  (4) Say what you want.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Do you want the computed ratio to be written to the output, or do you only want it to be used to compute the new value? (5) Include an example. Modify the existing (2015-10-13 07:00:02 2015-10-19 00:00:00   45   1900) example, or add a new one (maybe only two or three days) if you believe that that would be clearer (or do both). *Show* the values you want in your output, and *explain* how they are computed from the input. (6) Ping me again when you’re ready for me to look at it again. … … … P.S. Thanks for the “accept” and the praise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will do what you want
(if I understand your requirements correctly). 
I took the liberty of extrapolating your specification
to allow the input to have one header line
and then any number of lines with date/time ranges. 
I’ll illustrate this, and discuss it further, below.

```
#!/bin/sh
if IFS= read header
then
        printf "%s\n" "$header"
else
        echo 'EOF on first line!' >&2
        exit 1
fi
while read start_date start_time end_date end_time other_data           # See note, below.
do
        start_epoch=$(date +"%s" -d "$start_date $start_time")  ||  {
                echo "Error processing start date&time $start_date $start_time" >&2
                exit 1
        }
        end_epoch=$(date +"%s" -d "$end_date $end_time")  ||  {
                echo "Error processing end date&time $end_date $end_time" >&2
                exit 1
        }
        if [ "$end_epoch" -lt "$start_epoch" ]
        then
                echo "End date&time $end_date $end_time is before start date&time $start_date $start_time" >&2
                # Now what?
                continue
        fi
        ok_seq=1        # Flag: we are moving forward.
        current_date="$start_date"
        current_time="$start_time"
        while [ "$ok_seq" -ne 0 ]
        do
                # Most days end at 23:59:59.
                eod_time="23:59:59"
                eod_epoch=$(date +"%s" -d "$current_date $eod_time")  ||  {
                        # This should never happen.
                        echo "Error processing end-of-day date&time $current_date $eod_time" >&2
                        exit 1
                }
                if [ "$end_epoch" -lt "$eod_epoch" ]    # We’re passing the end of the date/time range.
                then
                        if [ "$current_date" != "$end_date" ]
                        then
                                # Sanity check -- this should not happen.
                                echo "We're finishing, but the current date is $current_date and the end date is $end_date" >&2
                        fi
                        eod_time="$end_time"
                        ok_seq=0
                fi
                                                                        # See note, below.
                printf "%s %s %s %s      %s\n" "$current_date" "$current_time" "$current_date" "$eod_time" "$other_data"
                # We could also use +"%F" for the full YYYY-mm-dd date.
                current_date=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d" -d "$current_date next day")  ||  {
                        # This shouldn’t happen.
                        echo "Error getting next day after $current_date" >&2
                        exit 1
                }
                current_time="00:00:01"
        done
done
```

Discussion:

- Read the header line. 
  If this fails, abort the script. 
  If it succeeds, write the line to the output. 
  If (as your question shows) you don’t want the header in your output,
  remove the `printf "%s\n" "$header"` statement.
- As mentioned above:
  loop, reading start/end/value lines from the input
  until we reach the end of the input (or get a fatal error). 
  If you don’t want to do this,
  remove the `while`, the `do`, and the corresponding `done`.
- Read the start date, start time, end date, end time, and other data. 
  `other_data` includes everything after the end time,
  i.e., val1 and val2 (and all the space between them).
- Use the `date +"%s" -d "date/time string"` command
  to convert arbitrary date/time strings to Unix “epoch times” —
  the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 (GMT). 
  This lets us validate input (and exit in case of error),
  and also gives us numbers that we can compare.
  (Although I suppose we could just do string comparison
  on values formatted as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.)
- If the end date/time is before the start date/time,
  skip this record and go to the next line. 
  If you’d rather do something else (like terminate) in this case,
  change this code.
- Set a flag (`ok_seq`) that we will use
  to control the loop that steps through the days. 
  Initialize the start date/time for the first day
  to be the start date/time for the entire period.
- On each output line, the start date and the end date are the same. 
  On most lines, the end of day (eod) time is 23:59:59. 
  If (same date) + 23:59:59 is greater (later) than
  the end-of-period date/time,
  then we are on the last day (output line) of the range. 
  Set the eod time to the end time,
  and set `ok_seq` to 0 so we will exit the loop.
- Write a line of output, including the “other data” (val1 and val2, etc.)
- Compute the next day’s date. 
  Set the start time to 00:00:01,
  which will appear on each output line except for the first.

Example:

```
$ cat input
      startdate             end date         val1    val2
2015-10-13 07:00:02 2015-10-19 00:00:00      45      1900
2015-11-01 08:30:00 2015-11-05 15:00:00      42      6083
2015-12-27 12:00:00 2016-01-04 12:34:56      17      quux

$ ./script < input
      startdate             end date         val1    val2
2015-10-13 07:00:02 2015-10-13 23:59:59      45      1900
2015-10-14 00:00:01 2015-10-14 23:59:59      45      1900
2015-10-15 00:00:01 2015-10-15 23:59:59      45      1900
2015-10-16 00:00:01 2015-10-16 23:59:59      45      1900
2015-10-17 00:00:01 2015-10-17 23:59:59      45      1900
2015-10-18 00:00:01 2015-10-18 23:59:59      45      1900
2015-10-19 00:00:01 2015-10-19 00:00:00      45      1900
2015-11-01 08:30:00 2015-11-01 23:59:59      42      6083
2015-11-02 00:00:01 2015-11-02 23:59:59      42      6083
2015-11-03 00:00:01 2015-11-03 23:59:59      42      6083
2015-11-04 00:00:01 2015-11-04 23:59:59      42      6083
2015-11-05 00:00:01 2015-11-05 15:00:00      42      6083
2015-12-27 12:00:00 2015-12-27 23:59:59      17      quux
2015-12-28 00:00:01 2015-12-28 23:59:59      17      quux
2015-12-29 00:00:01 2015-12-29 23:59:59      17      quux
2015-12-30 00:00:01 2015-12-30 23:59:59      17      quux
2015-12-31 00:00:01 2015-12-31 23:59:59      17      quux
2016-01-01 00:00:01 2016-01-01 23:59:59      17      quux
2016-01-02 00:00:01 2016-01-02 23:59:59      17      quux
2016-01-03 00:00:01 2016-01-03 23:59:59      17      quux
2016-01-04 00:00:01 2016-01-04 12:34:56      17      quux
```

Observe that it has no problem rolling over,
not only from one month to the next, but also from one year to the next.

---

**Note:**
When I wrote the above version of the script,
I couldn’t figure out how to capture the white space
between the end time and val1, so I was getting output that looked like

```
      startdate             end date         val1    val2
2015-10-13 07:00:02 2015-10-13 23:59:59 45      1900
2015-10-14 00:00:01 2015-10-14 23:59:59 45      1900
2015-10-15 00:00:01 2015-10-15 23:59:59 45      1900
                    ︙
```

so I “cheated”,
by building the ‘right amount’ of space into the `printf` command
(before the last `%s`). 
But if you change the spacing in your input,
the above version of the script will again
produce incorrectly aligned columns. 
I figured out how to fix it, although it’s a little messy. 
Replace the `while …` `do` … `start_epoch=…` lines with:

```
while read start_date start_time end_date other_data
do
        # $other_data includes end_time and all the following values.
        # Break them apart:
        end_time="${other_data%%[       ]*}"
        other_data="${other_data#"$end_time"}"
        start_epoch=…
```

where `end_time` has been removed from the `read` command,
and the characters between the brackets `[` and the `]`
are a space and a tab. 
So now `other_data` contains the spaces before val1. 
Then change the `printf` to

```
                printf "%s %s %s %s%s\n" "$current_date" "$current_time" "$current_date" "$eod_time" "$other_data"
```

(note that there is *no* space between the fourth and fifth `%s`). 
So now you’re done.

Comment: Thank you G(enious)-Man.
Thanks for your effort. I am totally new of shell scripting.
I didnt run this query till now. once i run i will let you know the update.
once again
Thank you G-Man.
Regards,
Anbu K

Comment: I got one modification today which is given below,

calculate  r1= the ratio of timespent 1st day (i.e. end-start on day 1)  / totaltime

Comment: I got one modification today which is given below,
if we split the single row to multiple rows depend upon the date diff. of the start date and end date. then val1 should be calculated by the following formula.
 val2=1900, val1=45
 calculate 1st row val1= the ratio of timespent 1st day (i.e. end-start on day 1) / val2.
calculate 2nd row val1= the ratio of timespent 2nd day (i.e. end-start on day 1) / val2.
calculate 3rd row val1= the ratio of timespent  3rd day (i.e. end-start on day 1) / val2.
 till the enddate.
please help me to do this @G-Man

Comment: (1) Thanks for the thanks; you’re welcome. (2) We (at [SE]) typically ask that if you have a new question, you should [***ask a new question***](/questions/ask). This seems like a small enough change that I won’t demand that, but I will request that you [edit your question](/posts/318044/edit) to specify the additional features that you want.  Include an example or two. And be clear and unambiguous. (3) Your second and third comments are inconsistent.  The second says “calculate r1=…timespent… / totaltime”, the third says something confusing about “val1= *(something)* / val2”. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  If one of them is wrong, you can delete it.  Move your mouse pointer to the end (to the right of your name and the time-of-posting), and a red circle with a white X (like ⓧ) will appear; click on that.  If they’re both right, be sure to explain that in your edit to the question. (4) ”Ping” me again with another “@” message when you’ve done that. (5) The official way to thank somebody who has answered your question is to [accept his answer](/help/someone-answers).  When you get a little more reputation, you will also be able to [vote up good answers](/help/privileges/vote-up).

Comment: Sorry G-Man. I have edited the question now. I don't know the protocols.
I accepted your answer. and its extraordinary query explanation which i ever seen anywhere. Thanks a lot.

I got appreciation from My manager. and you are inspiring me to learn unix by using your code.

very simple and less code. Super.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are looking to get rid of the top header line. Let's say the function you are getting this input from is called 'timefunc'. You might want to try piping timefunc's output in a cut command like this:

```
timefunc | cut -d$'\n' -f2
```

The output is now:

```
2015-10-13 07:00:02 2015-10-19 00:00:00      45      1900
```

Comment: my goal is to split the date.if the date difference of start date and end date is >=1.
and do some calculation in val1, val 2 columns.

Comment: Hi can you tell me how to take a hive table columns as a input for this query. Thanks, AAA

Answer (score 0):

you can strip the header lines from your output with grep:

```
inputcmd | grep -v startdate
```

Comment: Hi

can you tell me how to take a hive table columns as a input for this query.

Thanks,
AAA