# How to compare date without having year parameter, in shell script?

Tags: shell-script

I have a log file in Linux looking like this :

```
Mar  2 09:46:45 [rest of the log]
```

As many services logs in Debian Linux it does not contain year information, I guess because logs meant to be very recent events.

I want to check if this line of log is for last ten minutes or not, so i did this :

```
Now="$(date '+%b %d %H:%M:%S')"
echo "Now : $Now"

TENMINSEC=$(date -d 'now - 10 minutes' '+%s')
echo "Ten min before : ${TENMINSEC}"

LOGDAT=$(date -d 'Mar  2 09:45:40' '+%s')
echo "LOGDAT : ${LOGDAT}"

if [ $LOGDAT -ge $TENMINSEC ];then 
    echo "Log date is greater"; 
fi
```

It convert LOGDAT and last ten minutes to seconds and compare them.

But i got confused if it is doing what i want it to do ? Isn't it effect the result if it dos not contain year information? how can i fix it?

Ps:

I have no problem , reading line of log file. and what it read from log file will be replaced with date in code (Mar  2 09:45:40);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split the date range into days using script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318044/how-to-split-the-date-range-into-days-using-script)

Comment: @roaima , that is good idea , let me test it.

Comment: See also `ts -r` (from moreutils)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not given a year in the date string, GNU `date` (which you seem to be using) will assume the date refers to the current year:

```
$ date -d 'Mar  2 09:45:40'
Sat Mar  2 09:45:40 CET 2019
```

Converting this date to Unix time and comparing it to some other date on the same format, would therefore do the right thing, except at around midnight on new years eve.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure what the date command produces for a given date you can always try it. In this specific situation, you'd remove the `+%s` so you could read the result:

```
date -d 'Mar 2 09:45:40'    # "02 Mar 2019 09:45:40"
```

Alternatively, given a time in seconds since the epoch you could convert that value back to a readable date:

```
time=1546300800
date --date "@$time"        # "01 Jan 2019 00:00:00"
```